# DownloadFileCompleted event not being called

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, webclient

I am trying to download a file from a server and the "DownloadFileCompleted" Event is not being called. 
Does anybody have any idea why?

Source:

```
Public Event DownloadFileCompleted As AsyncCompletedEventHandler

Public Sub DownloadCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    MsgBox("Downloaded")
End Sub

Private Function DLOAD()
    Try
        Dim WebClientT As New System.Net.WebClient()
        AddHandler WebClientT.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf DownloadFileCompletedD
        ByteArray = WebClientT.DownloadData("https://ip/file.filetype")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That event is only called when you use "DownloadFileAsync", because you're downloading synchronously the thread will wait to download all bytes without calling the event. then you don't need this event. Complete downloading will be always below DownloadData.

If you call this metod use

```
AddHandler WebClientT.DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf DownloadCompleted
WebClientT.DownloadDataAsync(uri)
```

More info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: how do i define an Uri

Comment: If i do that then i get an error saying "Expression does not produce a value."